# SharePoint REST query select items where column values are not equal

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

What is the REST query to obtain all items from a list where the value of two different columns for a given item are different.

Take the query: `http://<site_collection>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(<list_name>)/items?$select=ePR_x0020_NameId,ePurchaseRequestName&$filter=(ePR_x0020_NameId ne ePurchaseRequest)`

`ePR_x0020_NameId` is a lookup column with the title "ePR Name".  How do I properly use the `$expand` parameter to get the text of this column rather than the numeric value that is returned?

The query

`http://<site_collection>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(<list_name>)/items?$select=ePR_x0020_NameId,ePurchaseRequestName`

returns `ePR_x0020_NameId` as numeric value, not the string that is in the lookup column.

So when I try to add a filter parameter to this query to return only items where "ePR Name" and "ePurchaseRequestName" are not equal, I get a "The webpage cannot be found".

What is the proper REST query to return items where the column values "ePR Name" and "ePurchaseRequestName" are not equal?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you'll be able to do that.  Although it does seem like in the oData spec you should be able to [filter by comparing two fields](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44522790/988264), the examples given in that answer look like they are referencing oData v4, and [SharePoint implements oData v3](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/175027/8992).

In any case, I tried a bunch of tests and whenever I tried to add a filter to compare two fields against each other, I got

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "-2147024809, System.ArgumentException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "Value does not fall within the expected range."
        }
    }
}
```

even when comparing two text fields against each other, much less trying to comapre a text field to an expanded lookup field.

If you *were* able to do it, my guess is the query would look something like

```
http://<site_collection>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(<list_name>)/items?$select=ePR_x0020_Name/Title,ePurchaseRequestName&$expand=ePR_x0020_Name&$filter=(ePR_x0020_Name/Title ne ePurchaseRequest)
```

that is, assuming the lookup is to the `Title` field in the lookup list.  Without the filter, this will let you see the text value of the lookup instead of the Id:

```
http://<site_collection>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(<list_name>)/items?$select=ePR_x0020_Name/Title,ePurchaseRequestName&$expand=ePR_x0020_Name
```

Comment: thanks.  I'll try this and see what I can get.